# How to merge multiple returned lists into one

Tags: python

The code below result to list of lists: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`
How to modify it so the result is a simple list:`[1,2,3,4,5,6]?

```
def functA():
    return [1,2,3]
def functB():
    return [4,5,6]
def functC():
    return None

functs=[functA, functB, functC]

result=[a for a in [funct() for funct in functs] if a]

print result
```

Comment: have a look at list.extend

Comment: I would like to achieve this while being inside of list comprehension.

Comment: All of the answers that were given directly here are bad, because one of the most common/standard ways to solve the problem is by using a list comprehension in the right way, and the code **is already using** a list comprehension to gather results from the functions. All we need to do is rearrange it: `[a for a in [funct() for funct in functs] if a]` -> `[a for funct in functs if funct() for a in funct()]`. Rather than doing the filtering, it would be better to just return `[]` rather than `None` - as they say, "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten using a list comp also:

```
result=[ x for y in (a for a in (funct() for funct in functs) if a) for x in y]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) method:

For instance, this code:

```
from itertools import chain
print list(chain.from_iterable([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
```

Will print out:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

In your case, you can use:

```
result = list(chain.from_iterable(a for a in [funct() for funct in functs] if a))
```

`result` will then be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: `list(chain(*[a for a in [funct() for funct in functs] if a]))` will also work

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `chain` from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

However your function should return an empty list instead of `None` since this is friendlier with the expected format.

Since the first list of lists is temporary I made it a generator sequence.

```
from itertools import chain

def functA():
    return [1,2,3]

def functB():
    return [4,5,6]

def functC():
    return [] # returns an empty list, in line with what is expected.

functs=[functA, functB, functC]

result = list(chain(*(a() for a in functs)))

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to use a list comprehension, try this one:

```
result= [item
         for sublist in [funct()
                         for funct in functs]
         if sublist is not None
         for item in sublist]
```